# Flutter TextFormField inputFormatters regular expression (RegEx) doesn't work

Tags: regex, flutter, numbers, textformfield, inputformatter

I want to have a regular expression in flutter on my TextFormField, that **only numbers between -999 & 999** can be put in. When I tested the expression everything worked how I wanted to, but I don't know why I can not write "-" in the TextFormField.
The maximum numbers and that a number **should not start with 0 works** perfectly fine, but all the time I try to add a minus it doesn't work.
I would be thankful for any help!

```
 TextFormField(
              decoration: kTextFieldDecoration,
              style: kCustomNumberBoxTextStyle,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              initialValue: number.toString(),
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp(r'^-?[1-9]([0-9]{1,2})?')),
              ],
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                if (newValue != "") {
                  setState(() {
                    number = int.parse(newValue);
                  });
                  widget.onTap(int.parse(newValue));
                }
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Try `^-?(?:[1-9](?:[0-9]{0,2})?)?$`

Comment: Thank you very much that's it!
It'd be amazing if you could write a answer to explain, what I did wrong for preventing issues next time and that others who face it know it as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `^-?[1-9]([0-9]{1,2})?` regex makes the initial hyphen optional, which is fine, but the `[1-9]` part *requires* a non-zero digit. Moreover, you missed the `$` anchor at the end, and the regex can match anything after the third digit.

In order to be able to insert a single `-`, you need to make the digit matching parts optional.

You can thus use

```
^-?(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/goLNdx/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - an optional `-` char
- `(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
  - `[0-9]{0,2}` - any zero, one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.